# Question closed for not being focused enough

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/112910/why-is-jerome-debneys-last-work-not-published) seems to have many sub-questions, but indeed they are not sub-questions, they are the reasons why this question was asked.

Comment: Those still seem to be speculative in nature anyway, i.e. "opinion" questions, and thus off-topic.